# The 'body' part is not visible after using ' bottomNavigationBar' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar, flutter-design

Whenever i use the **bottomNavigationBar:** it dose not show the **body:** part on screen but when i remove the **bottomNavigationBar:** then it shows the **body:**
Here is the **code**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        actions: <Widget>[],
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffd81b60),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _getNavBar(context),

      body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 300.0),
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 10,
          child: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => mealwisePage()));
              },
              color: Colors.pink,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Meal Wise',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                ),), ), ), ), ]),);}
_getNavBar(context) {
  return Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        child: ClipPath(
          clipper: NavBarClipper(),
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                  Colors.pink,
                  Colors.pink.shade800,
                ])), ),),),],);}
```

> No error is showing just body is invisible on the screen

Any Solution Please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fount that it is because of using **Stack** it overlaps with body so i changed it 
from:

```
return Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        child: ClipPath(
          clipper: NavBarClipper(),
          child: Container(),),)],)
```

To

```
return Container(
      height: 90,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        child: ClipPath(
          clipper: NavBarClipper(),
          child: Container(),),),],),)
```

Answer (score 0):

bottom navigation is part of scaffold constructor `Widget bottomNavigationBar` and not the body hence refactor your code as shown below

```
     Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffd81b60),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,

      body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child:Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 40.0, 40.0, 25.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Home',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),),), ], ),),
        SizedBox(height: 200.0),         

    ]),//listview
 bottomNavigationBar: _getNavBar(context),
);//scaffold
```

**update edit**

```
child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
```

you must give a value to this `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,`
 example `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .98,`

Comment: The code is as it is as you are saying,Actually while posting the question stackoverflow suggest me to reduce the code so while reducing the code it becomes like this sorry for that now i have updated the code in question.

Comment: did'nt work for me, actually this is not the complete code and i am unable to post complete code in the question.here is complete code of bottom navigation bar that i used: https://github.com/stevendz/customappbar_yt/blob/master/lib/main.dart

Comment: i identified , it is because of Stack Widget so i used it in a container with height:100 now everything is visible above the container,so please tell me if you know any other good approach.